# Carry a set of data from coldfusion to jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, coldfusion

I'm trying to do something like this, I don't think I have the syntax quite right:

```
<cfset info = '{ name: "name", address:"address"}' />

<img data-info='#info#' onClick="CheckInfo()" />

<script>

    function CheckInfo()
    {
         var info = $(event.target).attr("data-info"); 
         console.log(info.name);
    }

</script>
```

"info" looks correct in the console if I output it, but I can't get the members. info.name is undefined.

Answer (score 3):

The attribute `data-info` contains a string, not an object. If you called `.data('info')` on the image, you'd retrieve the entire value. To do what you want, you'd have to break it into two data attributes:

```js
function CheckInfo() {
 var info = {name:$(event.target).data("info-name"),address:$(event.target).data("info-address")}; 
 console.log(info);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<cfset info = '{ name: "name", address:"address"}' />

<img data-info-name="myName" data-info-address="myAddress" onClick="CheckInfo()" width="100" height="100" />
```

Although, it would be cleaner to do something more along the lines of the below:

```js
/* Use jQuery to assign a listener, instead of filling HTML with JS */
$('img').on('click',function() {
 var info = {name:$(this).data("info-name"),address:$(this).data("info-address")}; 
 console.log(info);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<cfset local.info = '{ name: "name", address:"address"}' />

<!-- CF code example -->
<img data-info-name="#local.info.name#" data-info-address="#local.info.address#" width="100" height="100" /> 

<!-- Final rendered HTML example -->
<img data-info-name="myName" data-info-address="myAddress" width="100" height="100" />
```

Answer (score 1):

make the json string valid by wrapping keys with double quotes

```
{ "name": "Dan", "address":"1234 Main St, City, ST 00000"}
```

since the value is json then you need to parse it as such

```
var info = $.parseJSON($(event.target).attr("data-info"));
```